# how can i search and copy only the searchedWords to the next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

This code is to copy words 'small' 'medium' 'large' it is static but i have list of 
    words in column(B) which is used search in the (D) column and if found copy words 
    in 'E' column

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindSize()

Dim c As Range, s, i As Long
s = Array("small", "medium", "large")
For Each c In Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
If InStr(UCase(c), UCase(s(i))) > 0 Then
c.Offset(, 1) = UCase(s(i))
Exit For
End If
Next i
Next c 
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't a worksheet formula be the way to go rather than writing a macro?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with Mr. Bananas that a simple formula is a better solution. Off the top of my head I would use:

> =TRIM(IFERROR(IF(FIND("small",LOWER(B2))>0,"Small ",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(FIND("medium",LOWER(B2))>0,"Medium
>   ",""),"")&IFERROR(IF(FIND("large",LOWER(B2))>0,"Large ",""),""))

Which you would copy down the column. The formula searches for each text string (small, medium & large) returns the proper text with a space at the end. The IFERROR deals with the #VALUE result of the find when B cell doesn't contain a particular string. Results then are concatenated (& operators) and then trimmed of extra spaces. Hope this helps.